# Encrypting & Decrypting MD5 in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, md5

I can insert a row by using code below.

```
USE pmdb;
INSERT INTO md5_tbl (md5_val, username, password) VALUES(MD5('abcdef'), 'usna', MD5('Aa123456'));
```

How can i decrypt or decode password when i select the row by using username field?

Comment: in addition to what others have said (MD5 is hashing not encryption): MD5 is Broken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, MD5 is a hashing algorithm = no decryption possible (except brute force attacks, but...)

Secondly, don't use MD5 for hashing passwords, it isn't secure at all. Instead, use **at least** SHA family + technique called "salting".

Answer (score 5):

MD5 can't be decrypt,

You should search the value of the MD5 of your entered password in your database to compare.

```
SELECT * FROM md5_tbl WHERE password = MD5('password') AND username = 'username'
```

Answer (score 3):

The idea with MD5 is that you don't decrypt it again. Instead encrypt the password that the user provides and compare it to the value stored in your table.

Answer (score 3):

A hash cannot be reversed. It is not "encryption". I suggest you take a look [here](http://www.phpbb.com/kb/article/difference-between-encryption-and-hashing/) for an explanation of the difference between hashing and encryption.

That said, I suppose you're trying to check a user's password upon login. The way it's done with hashes is:

1. Hash password entered by user.
2. Retrieve hashed password from database.
3. Compare hashes (byte-per-byte) -- if they match, the password is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. MD5 is not an encryption algorithm, it's a hashing algorithm.

What you do is that you hash the newly entered password and compare it with the hash stored in the database:

```
select *
from md5_tbl
where username = ?username and password = md5(?password)
```

Answer (score 2):

Rainbow tables? ;-)

MD5 is a one-way hashing algorithm. It can't be "decrypted".

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from md5_tbl where username = 'username' AND password = MD5('password')
```

Don't forget to sanitize the input to prevent SQL injection attacks.

If you want to reverse MD5, you can't do that. Look into RSA, if you want to encrypt & decrypt something.